# Why is my method processing an element that has been removed from an array?

Tags: bash

I have an array of strings that represent dates:

```
filedates=()
```

I have to find the oldest date in the array by comparing the current element to a temporary oldest date ($tempOldestDate)

After I find the oldest date in the array, I then check if there are three elements with that same date in the array. If there is not 3 elements that match the date, I remove those elements.
 The logic I have for this part works fine. 
**I print the original array and then the resulting array and it clearly shows that those elements were removed:**

The part I'm struggling with is when I try to call my **find_oldest_date** method again from within the remove_oldest_date method with the **result** array. Calling $set_temp_oldest_date with the $result array works as expected. But making a call right after to $find_oldest_date keeps returning the element that was removed... I cant figure out why it keeps including the deleted element...

The output shows the temporary date as the one I removed...
Not sure how this is possible as `result=()` is clearly showing that this element has been removed.
**EDIT**:
A script to test the functionality:
P.S. Although I do appreciate chances to optimize the script , please just try your best at targeting the questions I'm asking and then leave feedback for optimizing. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
filedates=(20200420,20200420,20200420,20200419,20200419,20200419,20200416,20200416)

find_oldest_date (){
    arr="$1"
    echo "Searching for oldest date in directory..."
    for file in $arr; do
        currentDate=$file
        if [ $currentDate -lt $tempOldestDate ]; then
            oldestDateFound=$currentDate
        else
            oldestDateFound=$tempOldestDate
        fi
    done
    oldestDateFoundFormatted=`date -d $oldestDateFound +%Y-%m-%d`
    echo "Oldest date found in directory: "$oldestDateFoundFormatted
    printf "\n"
}

set_temp_oldest_date (){
    arr=$1
    echo "Setting temporary oldest date..."
    currentOldestDate=($arr[1])
    currentOldestDateFormatted=`date -d $currentOldestDate +%Y-%m-%d`
    echo "Temporary oldest date: "$currentOldestDateFormatted
    printf "\n"
}
find_three_files_with_oldest_date(){
    arr=$1
    i=0
    echo Searching for all three files with date: $oldestDateFoundFormatted ...
    for date in $arr; do
    currentDate=$date
    if [ $currentDate == $oldestDateFound ]; then
    ((i=i+1))
    fi
    done

    printf "\n"
    echo "*****************"
    echo "$i file(s) found"
    echo "*****************"
    printf "\n"
    filesMissing=$((3-$i))

    if [ $i == 3 ]; then
        echo "*****************"
        echo  All 3 files found
        echo "*****************"
    else
        echo "*****************"
        echo "$filesMissing file(s) missing"
        echo "*****************"
        printf "\n"
        echo $(remove_oldest)
        printf "\n"
        echo $(find_oldest_date)           
        echo $(find_three_files_with_oldest_date)
    fi
}
remove_oldest(){
        arr=$1
        echo "Removing files with date $oldestDateFound ..."
        delete="$oldestDateFound"
        result=("${arr[@]}")
        echo before: ${arr[@]}
        printf "\n"
        echo to delete: ${delete[@]}
        printf "\n"
        for i in $result; do
        for host in ${delete[@]}; do
        result=( "${result[@]/$host}" )
        done
        done
        echo after: ${result[@]}
        printf "\n"
        echo Starting new search with updated/filtered list of dates
        echo $(set_temp_oldest_date "${result[@]}")
        echo $(find_oldest_date "${result[@]}")
        echo $(find_three_files_with_oldest_date "${result[@]}")

}

set_temp_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
find_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
find_three_files_with_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
```

Comment: Please provide test dates with which we can try your code.  The `-lt` operator is not geared towards comparing dates, so I am curious to see what you use.  One detail, do not use backticks to run commands, use `$()`.  Like in `oldestDateFoundFormatted=$(date -d $oldestDateFound +%Y-%m-%d)`.  Also provide a sample script which uses these functions, again for us to use in tests.  Read [mcve] on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Nic3500. To clarify - i compare the dates by using a string value that represents the date so in that case I should be OK using the ```lt``` operator? What do you think?

Comment: As presented, `-lt` is ok, since the dates are all represented with a number, with the correct order.

Comment: Its strange that the call:
echo $(find_oldest_date "${result[@]}")
is returning the element that has been removed.. can't figure out why this is

Comment: Put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, you will see some things to fix.  Ex. in `set_temp_oldest_date()`, there is a line `currentOldestDate=($arr[1])`, that line is not valid, and causes the next line to fail as well.  Run your script line per line in a terminal, you will see things that fail.